# Caliburn Micro and NavigationPane

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, navigation, caliburn.micro

for my wpf project I am using caliburn micro and [NavigationPane](http://navigationpane.codeplex.com/). 
My question is how can I emplement conductor functionality. That the best way to change current screen by cliking on NavigationPaneItem.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have your Screen manager view model implemented inheriting the CaliburnM's `Conductor<T>` base.

So in your NavigationPane's item click, you can call CaliburnM's `ChangeActiveItem()` method to swap the screens. You have to pass in the new screen view model to that method along with a boolean which determines the closure of the previously active screen.

PS: I am not aware of NavigationPane functionality but I am pretty much familiar with CaliburnM.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but that's exactly what I wanted to avoid, write code into click event. I did not found a nice way to use NavigationPane with MVVM. There is a Telerick control for WPF but it is not free. I have created simple buttons without "Outlook" behavior.